# How to pass list containing dictionary in html template and access its values

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

In django i have this list

```
my_list=[{'id':1,'username':'sometext'},{'id':2,'username':'someothertext'}]
```

i am passing this list into the template

```
   return render(request,'template.html',{'mylist':my_list})
```

This is my template.html

```
               {% for i in mylist.items %}
                   <tr>
                                        
                      <td>{{ mylist.id }}</td>
                      <td>{{ mylist.username }}</td>
                                 
                   </tr>
               {% endfor %}
```

But by doing this i didn't get the value of id and and username.

Comment: Use `<td>{{ i.id }}</td>` instead of using `<td>{{ mylist.id }}</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mylist` is a *list*, not a dictionary, so you should enumerate with:

```
{#     no .items ↓    #}
{% for item in mylist %}
  <tr>
    {# use item ↓ #}
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```